How do I select only filled-in values and use them in another worksheet in excel?
I have a large list of data parameters in excel that need to be filled in, where the first column is the parameter name, the second column is the value to be filled in and the third is the corresponding unit.
I would like to create a second sheet where only the values that are actually filled in are shown, with their corresponding name and unit. I don't want any gaps between them.
I am very much new to using conditionals in excel and VBA, so hope there is someone here who can help me out. I've already tried several things based on similar situations that I found online but can't seem to get the right method and I always end up either with gaps in between the values or a non-working code.
Thanks!

If you are using a newer version of Office (eg Office 365), simply use the Filter-Function.
Assuming that the parameter sheet is called "Sheet1", put the following formula to the second sheet:
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:C,Sheet1!B:B<>"","no data found")

Sheet1!A:C tells where you want to get the data from
Sheet1!B:B<>"" defines a filter: Display data only if the value in column B is not empty.
"no data found" writes the text if no matching data was found (no parameter is yet filled)
As this is a formula, it will update the list in the 2nd sheet automatically whenever something is changed in the parameter sheet.

Copy Filtered Values

Main
Sub CopyFilteredValues()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A2")
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in range """ _
                & .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Address(0, 0) _
                & """ of sheet """ & sws.Name & """!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount, 3)
    End With
            
    ' Return the values of the source range in an array.
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Write the rows that meet the conditions to the top of the array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If AreConditionsMet(Data(sr, 1), Data(sr, 2)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To 3
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Write the values from the top of the array to the destination sheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    With dws.Range("A2").Resize(, 3)
        ' Write.
        If dr > 0 Then .Resize(dr).Value = Data
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dr - .Row + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No row in the range """ & srg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ of sheet """ & sws.Name & """ meets the conditions!", _
            vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Filtered values copied.", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub

Help
Function AreConditionsMet(Value1 As Variant, Value2 As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsBlank(Value1) Then Exit Function
    If IsNumberCellValue(Value2) Then AreConditionsMet = True ' is a number
    ' Or:
    'If Not IsBlank(Value2) Then AreConditionsMet = True ' is not blank
End Function

Function IsBlank(Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If Len(CStr(Value)) = 0 Then IsBlank = True
End Function

Function IsNumberCellValue(Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then IsNumberCellValue = True
End Function

